What is a top margin that has clearance?
According to the WC3 specification:

The bottom margin of an in-flow block box with a 'height' of 'auto' collapses with its last in-flow block-level child's bottom margin, if:

the box has no bottom padding, and

the box has no bottom border, and

the child's bottom margin neither collapses with a top margin that has clearance, nor (if the box's min-height is non-zero) with the box's top margin.




Could someone explain what the last paragraph implies with an example please?

OK, prepare yourself for a bit of a wild ride. IMHO, you're incredibly unlikely to encounter this in practice. I've certainly never yet found a use for it.
What we need to know is that clearance is a state a box gets when it's moved down in order to clear a float in its block formatting context.
This is done with clear:left or clear:right or clear:both. If the box would otherwise be alongside a float on the side on which it's cleared, the box is moved down until its border-box is fully below the margin box of the float.
Now consider this example:


body {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
main {
  padding-top:1px;
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
aside {
  background-color: tan;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
header {
  margin-top:90px;
}
footer {
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
<body>
  <main>
    <aside>The aside</aside>
    <header></header>
    <footer></footer>
  </main> 
</body>



The aside element is the float. The top padding on the main element is to ensure that nothing can collapse with the top margin of the main or body elements.
Because the header and footer elements have no content, the margin-bottom on the main element, the margin-top on the header element and the margin-bottom on the footer element are all adjacent and collapse together, making a total vertical margin of 100px. The body element content box contains them, making its height 101px. (1px padding + 100px margin)
Now, let's add clear:left to the header element.


body {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
main {
  padding-top:1px;
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
aside {
  background-color: tan;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
header {
  margin-top:90px;
  clear:left;
}
footer {
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
<body>
  <main>
    <aside>The aside</aside>
    <header></header>
    <footer></footer>
  </main> 
</body>



Now the height of the body element is 211px!.
The border box of the header element is moved down 10px so that it clears the float. That is the header element has clearance. Since the top margin of the header element is attached to the border box, it too is moved down 10px. Then the bottom margin of the footer collapses with the top margin of the header and pushes the border box of the header down another 10px (100px - 90px).
We've now reached the conditions of your question. The footer element is the last in-flow block-level child of it's parent - the main element. The footer element has no bottom padding or border. Its bottom margin collapses with the top margin of an element that has clearance.
So the result is that the footer's bottom margin cannot collapse with the bottom margin of the main element, and so the total height of the content box of the body element is 1px + 100px + 10px + 100px.
Finally, consider what happens when the header's top margin is set to 101px instead of 90px.


body {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
main {
  padding-top:1px;
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
aside {
  background-color: tan;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
header {
  margin-top:101px;
  clear:left;
}
footer {
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
<body>
  <main>
    <aside>The aside</aside>
    <header></header>
    <footer></footer>
  </main> 
</body>



Notice that now the bottom margin of the main element collapses with the other margins again. That's because although the header element still has clear:left, its margin top is greater than the height of the float, so its border box is already below the bottom of the float, and so there's no need for it to move down. Since it doesn't move, the header element does not have clearance, and so the margins can all collapse.

first of all, thank you so much for a thorough explanation. There's a few nuances I'd like to clarify though:

Firefox is highlighting the footer's bottom margin below its border box (as if the footer's margin doesn't collapse with the header's top margin). https://ibb.co/NKcqNd2 As I understand, the browser is showing it incorrectly here?



If so, is it fair to say that, before the footer's bottom margin collapses with the header's top margin, it actually turns into the footer's top margin?



When the footer's bottom margin (100px) collapses with the header's top margin (90px) and pushes the header's border box down another 10px, why is the browser highlighting the header's border box (just like the footer's border box) in line with the floated box's bottom border box (as if they haven't been pushed down another 10px)?


I made the background of the main element blue to make it more obvious: https://ibb.co/rcgpccv Is this another inaccuracy of the browser? Or is it the way it's supposed to be according to this W3C spec that "the position of the element's top border edge is the same as it would have been if the element had a non-zero bottom border"? If so, then why do we get those 10px down? After the margins collapse, wouldn't it be more logical for those 10px just to go up instead and fill the margin up to the very top?


Also, I viewed this question you answered some time ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232549/margin-collapse-for-adjacent-siblings. If I understand it correctly, we have to add another element with clearing between the siblings to prevent them from collapsing. However, the WC3 spec says that "the bottom margin of an in-flow block-level element always collapses with the top margin of its next in-flow block-level sibling, unless that sibling has clearance". Does it mean that the quoted paragraph is a misinterpretation of the actual technique?


1, 2, & 3: Interpreting what Firefox's dev tools is showing is quite tricky. But basically what it shows is the used value of the margin before collapse. 4) We don't have to have an intervening element, but we can do. In essence, it's margins that must be adjacent, not sibling elements. Clearance simply guarantees that the margins will be non-adjacent.

@Zytonox - Unnumbered: the background of the main element looks correctly depicted to me. 111px height from the 1px padding +10px clearance move + 100px collapsed margin of header and footer".         ...more logical?" Maybe, but I doubt logic has anything to do with it. I suspect that the spec is just the codification of what Netscape Navigator was capable of doing in the mid 1990s.
