# I've a given a html and css code and facing a issue in it

Tags: html, css

The margin given to `.cls1` which is the `a` tag, is not getting applied. The left and right margin is applied, but not the top.

I'm trying to shift my "read more" button downwards but the given margin is not getting applied from the top.

Please don't give me a new approach for solving this, just tell me the reason or the shortcomings that are not allowing the `margin-top`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .divv {
      border-radius: 15px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: 530px;
      width: 400px;
    }
    
    img {
      margin: 10px;
      border-radius: 15px;
    }
    
    .cls {
      text-decoration: none;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 3px;
      margin: 18px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    .clss {
      position: relative;
      left: -23px;
    }
    
    h2 {
      margin: 10px;
    }
    
    p {
      line-height: 1.4em;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    
    .cls1 {
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 14px;
      background-color: rgb(222, 241, 250);
      border-radius: 28px;
      color: rgb(13, 85, 200);
      margin: 150px;
    }
    
    .diva {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- card.png is a file whcih contains a card image. Write html and css code to design this card-->
  <div class="divv">
    <img src="card.jpg" alt="" width="380px">
    <a class="cls" href="#">Nature</a>
    <a class="cls clss" href="#">Lake</a>
    <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum nulla magna sunt expedita animi laboriosam dicta ipsum dolor? Itaque, voluptates. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque, doloremque?</p>
    <a class="cls1" href="#">Read More</a>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Vertical spacing of inline box fragments is determined by the aligned line-heights of all fragments in the line box in which they are appear, and not by their box model dimensions. Or as CSS2 puts it, margin-top and margin-bottom "have no effect on non-replaced inline elements." Your `a.cls1` element is a non-replaced inline element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Margin collapse and clearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350805/margin-collapse-and-clearance)

Comment: @Alohci I think your margin collapse answer actually answers this.

Comment: @disinfor - No, it's not margin collapse. If the `a.cls1` element was block level, then its top margin would collapse with the bottom margin of the preceding p element but no further. The vertical gap between them would still be 150px.

Answer (score 1):

In .cs1 class I have added `display: table;` and `margin: 20px auto auto auto;`, maybe you want to do something like this

```css
.divv {
      border-radius: 15px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: 530px;
      width: 400px;
    }

    img {
      margin: 10px;
      border-radius: 15px;
    }

    .cls {
      text-decoration: none;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 3px;
      margin: 18px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .clss {
      position: relative;
      left: -23px;
    }

    h2 {
      margin: 10px;
    }

    p {
      line-height: 1.4em;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    .cls1 {
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 14px;
      background-color: rgb(222, 241, 250);
      border-radius: 28px;
      color: rgb(13, 85, 200);
      margin: 20px auto auto auto;
      display: table;
    }

    .diva {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="divv">
        <img src="card.jpg" alt="" width="380px">
        <a class="cls" href="#">Nature</a>
        <a class="cls clss" href="#">Lake</a>
        <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum nulla magna sunt expedita animi laboriosam dicta ipsum dolor? Itaque, voluptates. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque, doloremque?</p>
        <a class="cls1" href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why would you use `display: table` here? The `a` element is never used to store table style data.

Comment: Who says I can't use <a> tags to display tables?

Comment: Nobody says you can't, however, the property `display: table` doesn't make sense in this particular application. Changing it to `display: inline-block` or `block`, from a display property perspective makes more sense. Why would you use `display: table` in this example?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change because p tag is Blocked Element and a tag is Inline Element . You want to add margin-top in  tag , so you must be add a display:inline-block .

Thanks.